# Retornando valor 0 em um this.return java

Tags: java

Estou tentando fazer um programa que me traga o caminho critico de uma lista de atividades informadas pelo usuário, meu problema é: meu código esta retornando 0 para o calculo de folga.

[image]

No exemplo da imagem acima a folga nos vértices 2 e 6 é de 8, quando coloco esses dados no meu programa ele mostra que a folga é 0, o que estou achando estranho é que aparentemente o método esta correto.

Os códigos abaixo:

Class Atividade:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package trabalho_m3;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Atividade {

    private int idAtividade;
    private String nomeAtividade;
    private float tempoDuracao, tInicioCedo, tTerminoCedo, tTerminoTarde, tInicioTarde, folga;
    private int qtdPredecessores, qtdSucessores;
    private Atividade predecessores[], sucessores[];
    private int cnt_aux1 = 0, cnt_aux2 = 0;

    public Atividade(int id, String nome, float duracao, int nPre, int nSuc){
        this.idAtividade = id;
        this.nomeAtividade = nome;
        this.tempoDuracao = duracao;
        this.qtdPredecessores = nPre;
        this.qtdSucessores = nSuc;
        this.predecessores = new Atividade[this.qtdPredecessores];
        this.sucessores = new Atividade[this.qtdSucessores];
    }

    /*
    * Método que calcula os tempos de término e ínicio cedo das atividades
    */
    public void calcular_Tes_Tef(){

        // Cálculo do Tempo de Início Cedo da atividade (Tes).
        if(this.qtdPredecessores == 0){
            this.tInicioCedo = 0;
        } else {
            this.tInicioCedo = this.maxTefPredecessores(this.predecessores);
        }

        // Cálculo do Tempo de Término Cedo da atividade (Tef).
        this.tTerminoCedo = (this.tInicioCedo + this.tempoDuracao);
    }

    /*
    *  Método que calcula os tempos de término e ínicio tarde das atividades
    */
    public void calcular_Tlf_Tls(){

        // Cálculo do Tempo de Término Tarde da atividade (Tlf).
        if(this.qtdSucessores == 0){
            this.tTerminoTarde = this.tTerminoCedo;
        } else {
            this.tTerminoTarde = this.minTlsSucessores(this.sucessores);
        }

        // Cálculo do Tempo de Início Tarde da atividade (Tls).
        this.tInicioTarde = (this.tTerminoTarde - this.tempoDuracao);
    }

    /*
    * Método calcula a FOLGA(R) das atividades do projeto.
    */
    public void calcular_R(){
        this.folga = (this.tTerminoTarde - this.tTerminoCedo);
    }

    /*
    *  Método encontra o valor MÁXIMO do Tef entre os predecessores
    *  de uma atividade.
    */
    public float maxTefPredecessores(Atividade predecessores[]){
        float maxTef = predecessores[0].tTerminoCedo;
        for(int i = 1; i < predecessores.length; i++){
            if(maxTef < predecessores[i].tTerminoCedo){
                maxTef = predecessores[i].tTerminoCedo;
            }
        }
        return maxTef;
    }

    /*
    *  Método encontra o valor MÍNIMO do Tls entre os sucessores
    *  de uma atividade. 
    */
    public float minTlsSucessores(Atividade sucessores[]){
        float minTls = sucessores[0].tInicioTarde;
        for(int i = 1; i < sucessores.length; i++){
            if(sucessores[i].tInicioTarde < minTls){
                minTls = sucessores[i].tInicioTarde;
            }
        }
        return minTls;
    }

    /*
    *  Vincula a uma dada atividade suas precedencias, incluindo
    *  seus precedentes no Array predecessores[]. 
    */
    public void setarAtividadePredecessora(Atividade atividadePre){
        if(cnt_aux1 == this.qtdPredecessores){
            System.out.println("A atividade " + this.nomeAtividade + " nao suporta mais pre-requisitos!");
        } else {
            this.predecessores[this.cnt_aux1] = atividadePre;
            this.cnt_aux1++;
        }
    }

    /*
    *  Vincula a uma dada atividade seus sucessores. 
    */
    public void setarAtividadeSucessora(Atividade atividadeSuc){
        if(cnt_aux2 == this.qtdSucessores){
            System.out.println("A atividade " + this.nomeAtividade + " nao suporta mais atividades sucessoras!");
        } else {
            this.sucessores[this.cnt_aux2] = atividadeSuc;
            this.cnt_aux2++;
        }
    }

    // Retorna o NOME de uma atividade.
    public String getNome(){
        return this.nomeAtividade;
    }

    // Retorna a FOLGA(R) de uma atividade.
    public float getFolga(){
        return this.folga;
    }

        public float getPredecessores(){
        return this.qtdPredecessores;
    }

        public float getId(){
        return this.idAtividade;
    }

         public float getSucessores(){
        return this.qtdSucessores;
    }

         public Atividade[] getSucessores1() {
            return sucessores;
        }

    /*
    *  Imprime todas as informações de uma atividade
    */
    public void informacoesAtividade(){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Id: " + (this.idAtividade+1));
        System.out.println("Nome: " + this.nomeAtividade);

        if(this.qtdPredecessores == 0){
            System.out.println("Precedencia: --");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Precedencia: ");
            for(int i = 0; i < this.predecessores.length; i++){
                System.out.print(predecessores[i].nomeAtividade + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        if(this.qtdSucessores == 0){
            System.out.println("Sucessores: --");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Sucessores: ");
            for(int j = 0; j < this.sucessores.length; j++){
                System.out.print(sucessores[j].nomeAtividade + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Duração: " + this.tempoDuracao);
        System.out.println("Tempo Inicial Mais Cedo: " + (this.tInicioCedo+1));
        System.out.println("Tempo Final Mais Cedo: " + this.tTerminoCedo);
        System.out.println("Tempo Inicial Mais Cedo: " + (this.tInicioTarde+1));
                System.out.println("Tempo Final Mais Tarde: " + this.tTerminoTarde);
        System.out.println("Folga: " + this.folga);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Main:

```
package trabalho_m3;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TRABALHO_M3 {

   public static void Tes_Tef(Atividade[] Ativ){
        for(int i = 0; i < Ativ.length; i++){
            Ativ[i].calcular_Tes_Tef();
        }
    }



    public static void Tlf_Tls(Atividade[] Ativ){
        for(int i = (Ativ.length - 1); i >= 0; i--){
            Ativ[i].calcular_Tlf_Tls();
        }
    }

    public static void R(Atividade[] Ativ){
        for(int i = 0; i < Ativ.length; i++){
            Ativ[i].calcular_R();
        }
    }

    public static void atividadeInfo(Atividade[] Ativ){
        for(int i = 0; i < Ativ.length; i++){
            Ativ[i].informacoesAtividade();
        }
    }

    public static void caminhoCritico(Atividade[] Ativ){
        System.out.print("Caminho Critico: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < Ativ.length; i++){
            if(Ativ[i].getFolga() == 0.0){
                System.out.print(Ativ[i].getNome() + " ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       int qtd = 0;
       int aux;
       String rotulo;
       float peso;
       int predecessores, sucessores;
       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de atividades: ");
       qtd = s.nextInt();
       Atividade atividades[] = new Atividade[qtd];
       for (int i = 0; i <  qtd; i++){
           System.out.println("Informe o rótulo da atividade["+(i+1)+"]: ");
           rotulo = s.next();
           System.out.println("Informe a duracao da atividade["+(i+1)+"]: ");
           peso = s.nextFloat();
           System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de predecessores da atividade["+(i+1)+"]: ");
           predecessores = s.nextInt();
           System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de sucessores da atividade["+(i+1)+"]: ");
           sucessores = s.nextInt();
           atividades[i] = new Atividade(i,rotulo,peso,predecessores,sucessores);
           System.out.println("Pressione Enter para continuar..."); 
           System.in.read();
       }

        for (int i = 0; i <  qtd; i++){
            for (int b = 0; b <  qtd; b++){
                System.out.println("Atividade "+atividades[b].getNome()+" - ID = "+(atividades[b].getId()+1));
            }
            System.out.println("Pressione Enter para continuar..."); 
            System.in.read();
            if (atividades[i].getPredecessores() > 0 ) {
                System.out.println("Atividades Predecessoras de "+atividades[i].getNome());    
                for (int k=0; k<atividades[i].getPredecessores(); k++){
                           System.out.println("Informe o ID da atividade predecessora de numero "+(k+1)+" ...");
                           aux = (s.nextInt()-1);
                           atividades[i].setarAtividadePredecessora(atividades[aux]);
                           System.out.println("Pressione Enter para continuar..."); 
                           System.in.read();
                    }   
            } else {
                    System.out.println("A atividade ["+atividades[i].getNome()+"] não possui predecessores");
                    System.out.println("Pressione Enter para continuar..."); 
                    System.in.read();
            }
            for (int b = 0; b <  qtd; b++){
                System.out.println("Atividade "+atividades[b].getNome()+" - ID = "+(atividades[b].getId()+1));
            }
            System.out.println("Pressione Enter para continuar..."); 
            System.in.read();
            if (atividades[i].getSucessores() > 0 ) {
                    System.out.println("Atividades Sucessoras de "+atividades[i].getNome());
                    for (int k=0; k<atividades[i].getSucessores(); k++){
                           System.out.println("Informe o id da atividade sucessora de numero "+(k+1)+" ...");
                           aux = (s.nextInt()-1);
                           atividades[i].setarAtividadeSucessora(atividades[aux]);
                           System.out.println("Pressione Enter para continuar..."); 
                           System.in.read();
                    }   
            } else {
                    System.out.println("A atividade ["+atividades[i].getNome()+"] não possui sucessores");
                    System.out.println("Pressione Enter para continuar..."); 
                    System.in.read();
            }
        }
    Tes_Tef(atividades);
    Tlf_Tls(atividades);    
    atividadeInfo(atividades);
    R(atividades);
    caminhoCritico(atividades);
```

---

Um exemplo de entrada de dados (grafo com 4 vértices):

```
Informe a quantidade de atividades: 
4
Informe o rótulo da atividade[1]: 
A
Informe a duracao da atividade[1]: 
5
Informe a quantidade de predecessores da atividade[1]: 
0
Informe a quantidade de sucessores da atividade[1]: 
2
Pressione Enter para continuar...

Informe o rótulo da atividade[2]: 
B
Informe a duracao da atividade[2]: 
6
Informe a quantidade de predecessores da atividade[2]: 
1
Informe a quantidade de sucessores da atividade[2]: 
1
Pressione Enter para continuar...

Informe o rótulo da atividade[3]: 
C
Informe a duracao da atividade[3]: 
4
Informe a quantidade de predecessores da atividade[3]: 
1
Informe a quantidade de sucessores da atividade[3]: 
1
Pressione Enter para continuar...

Informe o rótulo da atividade[4]: 
D
Informe a duracao da atividade[4]: 
4
Informe a quantidade de predecessores da atividade[4]: 
2
Informe a quantidade de sucessores da atividade[4]: 
0
Pressione Enter para continuar...

Atividade A - ID = 1.0
Atividade B - ID = 2.0
Atividade C - ID = 3.0
Atividade D - ID = 4.0
Pressione Enter para continuar...

A atividade [A] não possui predecessores
Pressione Enter para continuar...

Atividade A - ID = 1.0
Atividade B - ID = 2.0
Atividade C - ID = 3.0
Atividade D - ID = 4.0
Pressione Enter para continuar...

Atividades Sucessoras de A
Informe o id da atividade sucessora de numero 1 ...
2
Pressione Enter para continuar...

Informe o id da atividade sucessora de numero 2 ...
3
Pressione Enter para continuar...

Atividade A - ID = 1.0
Atividade B - ID = 2.0
Atividade C - ID = 3.0
Atividade D - ID = 4.0
Pressione Enter para continuar...

Atividades Predecessoras de B
Informe o ID da atividade predecessora de numero 1 ...
1
Pressione Enter para continuar...

Atividade A - ID = 1.0
Atividade B - ID = 2.0
Atividade C - ID = 3.0
Atividade D - ID = 4.0
Pressione Enter para continuar...

Atividades Sucessoras de B
Informe o id da atividade sucessora de numero 1 ...
4
Pressione Enter para continuar...

Atividade A - ID = 1.0
Atividade B - ID = 2.0
Atividade C - ID = 3.0
Atividade D - ID = 4.0
Pressione Enter para continuar...

Atividades Predecessoras de C
Informe o ID da atividade predecessora de numero 1 ...
1
Pressione Enter para continuar...

Atividade A - ID = 1.0
Atividade B - ID = 2.0
Atividade C - ID = 3.0
Atividade D - ID = 4.0
Pressione Enter para continuar...

Atividades Sucessoras de C
Informe o id da atividade sucessora de numero 1 ...
4
Pressione Enter para continuar...

Atividade A - ID = 1.0
Atividade B - ID = 2.0
Atividade C - ID = 3.0
Atividade D - ID = 4.0
Pressione Enter para continuar...

Atividades Predecessoras de D
Informe o ID da atividade predecessora de numero 1 ...
2
Pressione Enter para continuar...

Informe o ID da atividade predecessora de numero 2 ...
3
Pressione Enter para continuar...

Atividade A - ID = 1.0
Atividade B - ID = 2.0
Atividade C - ID = 3.0
Atividade D - ID = 4.0
Pressione Enter para continuar...

A atividade [D] não possui sucessores
Pressione Enter para continuar...


Id: 1
Nome: A
Precedencia: --
Sucessores: B C 

Duração: 5.0
Tempo Inicial Mais Cedo: 1.0
Tempo Final Mais Cedo: 5.0
Tempo Inicial Mais Cedo: 1.0
Tempo Final Mais Tarde: 5.0
Folga: 0.0


Id: 2
Nome: B
Precedencia: A 
Sucessores: D 

Duração: 6.0
Tempo Inicial Mais Cedo: 6.0
Tempo Final Mais Cedo: 11.0
Tempo Inicial Mais Cedo: 6.0
Tempo Final Mais Tarde: 11.0
Folga: 0.0


Id: 3
Nome: C
Precedencia: A 
Sucessores: D 

Duração: 4.0
Tempo Inicial Mais Cedo: 6.0
Tempo Final Mais Cedo: 9.0
Tempo Inicial Mais Cedo: 8.0
Tempo Final Mais Tarde: 11.0
Folga: 0.0


Id: 4
Nome: D
Precedencia: B C 
Sucessores: --

Duração: 4.0
Tempo Inicial Mais Cedo: 12.0
Tempo Final Mais Cedo: 15.0
Tempo Inicial Mais Cedo: 12.0
Tempo Final Mais Tarde: 15.0
Folga: 0.0

Caminho Critico: A B D
```

No meu vértice C:

```
Duração: 4.0
Tempo Inicial Mais Cedo: 6.0
Tempo Final Mais Cedo: 9.0
Tempo Inicial Mais Cedo: 8.0
Tempo Final Mais Tarde: 11.0
Folga: 0.0
```

Usando o método para calcular a folga

```
folga = Tempo Final Mais Tarde - Tempo Final Mais Cedo
```

Na saída ele me retorna 0, mas o correto seria 2.

Meu método para calcular a folga.

```
public void calcular_R(){
        this.folga = (this.tTerminoTarde - this.tTerminoCedo);
    }
```

Os métodos para mostrar as informações (saída)

```
public static void atividadeInfo(Atividade[] Ativ){
        for(int i = 0; i < Ativ.length; i++){
            Ativ[i].informacoesAtividade();
        }
    }

public void informacoesAtividade(){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Id: " + (this.idAtividade+1));
        System.out.println("Nome: " + this.nomeAtividade);

        if(this.qtdPredecessores == 0){
            System.out.println("Precedencia: --");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Precedencia: ");
            for(int i = 0; i < this.predecessores.length; i++){
                System.out.print(predecessores[i].nomeAtividade + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        if(this.qtdSucessores == 0){
            System.out.println("Sucessores: --");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Sucessores: ");
            for(int j = 0; j < this.sucessores.length; j++){
                System.out.print(sucessores[j].nomeAtividade + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Duração: " + this.tempoDuracao);
        System.out.println("Tempo Inicial Mais Cedo: " + (this.tInicioCedo+1));
        System.out.println("Tempo Final Mais Cedo: " + this.tTerminoCedo);
        System.out.println("Tempo Inicial Mais Cedo: " + (this.tInicioTarde+1));
                System.out.println("Tempo Final Mais Tarde: " + this.tTerminoTarde);
        System.out.println("Folga: " + this.folga);
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Como sugestão para seu próximo tópico: Coloque um titulo mais claro (Ex. Resultado errado em algoritmo para caminho critico de um projeto). Alem disso, achei confuso o nome dos métodos calcular_Tes_Tef, calcular_Tlf_Tls , calcular_R e os Imports desnecessários.

Comment: Acredito que seu código não vai funcionar caso eu coloque uma atividade predecessora que ainda vai ser cadastrada ... ou uma sucessora que ja foi cadastrada no passado ... talvez para resolução do seu problema seja vantajoso utilizar grafos.

Answer (score 0):

O problema é porque você está imprimindo antes de calcular a folga.

Inverta a ordem da chamada dos métodos `atividadeInfo` e `R`.

Mude disso:

```
atividadeInfo(atividades);
R(atividades);
```

Para isso:

```
R(atividades);
atividadeInfo(atividades);
```

Sugestão: Utilize o debug. Esse tipo de problema é facilmente identificado debugando o código.